# Tracking clicks, dismisses and downloads from Android native smart banner

Tags: javascript, manifest.json, smartbanner

I want to track the [Android smart banner](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native) clicks, dismisses and downloads.
Downloads tracking would be done by the native app sending a deeplink from the web. I wonder if I could use `start_url` key from `manifest.json` to iclude a query, e.g.:

`start_url: myUrlToNativeApp/?trackingData=downloadedFromNativeSmartBanner`

For clicks and dismisses I see at [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) that I could use this code to track them though the docs example is for web app (comments are mine):

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {

  e.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {

    if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed') {
      console.log('User cancelled home screen install'); // In fact, user cancelled app download
      // Track dismissed event
    }
    else {
      console.log('User added to home screen'); // In fact, user clicked install
      // Track clicked event
    }
  });
});
```

**Does this code work for native apps too? If not, is there any other way to achieve it?**
**Can I track downloads changing `start_url` as above?**